# Write an exponential model - A doctor prescribes 125 milligrams of a therapeutic drug that decays by about 30% each hour.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am to write an exponential model of the scenario "A doctor prescribes 125 milligrams of a therapeutic drug that decays by about 30% each hour".

With that, I am to find the amount remaining after 3 hours.

My textbook solution says  $A=125e^{−0.3567t}$; $A≈43$ mg

I instead got $y=125e^{0.3*3}$; $A=307.45$ mg

Why is the correct solution $A=125e^{−0.3567t}$? And specifically where did $−0.3567$ come from?

Comment: Hint: $0.7^t  = e^{t\log (0.7)}  \approx e^{ - 0.3567t}$. Note that it decays by $30$ percentage, i.e., each hour it is $70$ percentage of what it was in the previous hour.

Comment: If $A = 125e^{kt}$ so that $A=125$ when $t=0$ then an hour later $A = 0.7*125 = 125*e^k$. Now solve for k.

Comment: I wouldn't have brought $e$ into it; the answer is $125\cdot (1-0.3)^3$ (which of course corresponds to the numerical answer in the book). On the numerical accuracy of the book's and your answer, observe the word "about" in the question and refrain from creating additional significant figures, especially beyond that implied in the quantities given (125mg, not 125.00mg).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A\,\mathrm{mg}$ be the amount remaining after $t\,\mathrm{h}.$ Your expression $A=125e^{0.3t}$ seems to have arisen from two modelling errors. Do note that:

1. The decay rate being $30\%$ (of itself) per hour means that by $t=1,$ $70\%$—not $30\%$—of it remains.
2. Since the drug is decreasing by a *constant proportion*, it is decreasing by a *decreasing amount* (as $A$ decreases over time). In other words, $A$ is decreasing exponentially—not *linearly*—with time. An analogy is compound interest versus simple interest.

The correct model is $$A=125(0.7^t)\\=125\exp\left(\ln0.7^t\right)\\=125\exp\left(t\ln0.7\right).$$

P.S. While we're on the topic of exponential decay: it follows from the above formula that this drug's half-life (time taken for half of any given amount of it to decay away) is $\displaystyle\frac{\ln(2)}{\ln(\frac{10}7)}$ hours.

Comment: On your last point, where does 10/7 come from? Is it just an equivalent of of 1/0.7 or have I missed something?

Comment: @DougFir Since 30% of the drug decays away every hour (whenever we start counting down; equivalently, for any starting amount), how long does it take for 50% of it to decay away? Forming a pair of simultaneous equations using the above formula, it becomes evident that yes the answer is $\displaystyle\frac{\ln(2)}{-\ln(\frac7{10})}$ hours.